# Assembly, can you move a function parameter's value into the .data section?

Tags: function, assembly, memory, x86

My question is, is it possible to move a function's parameter value into the .data section to "free" up register slot?

For example, If i have a function called int sort(int array[], int length), can I somehow put the array's length into the .data section as a global variable so I can call it? Currently, what I do is example

```
mov edi, [ebp + 12]
```

So I move the 2nd parameter into the edi register, however It would be nice if I could free up that register and use it for something else instantly.

Comment: Yes you can do it but using globals is not recommended. Use local variables. Incidentally, your argument is already in memory on the stack at `[ebp+12]` where you loaded it from, so what advantage do you hope to get from moving it to another memory location?

Comment: Yes, just like in C you can do `global_len = 10; foo();`.  And just like in C, that's a terrible design.  If you don't want to load it into EDI right away, then don't.  Look at the code C compilers emit: they try to make the most efficient use of registers to only load when needed, but when they do they keep data around.  Of course on a CISC like x86 where memory source operands are cheap, you can leave the data in memory if necessary, especially if you aren't writing it often.